# Allegro5: putting int's onto the screen

Tags: c++, text, fonts, allegro5

for example:

```
int score = 20;

int main(){
    al_draw_text(foo, foo, foo, foo, foo, "SCORE");

    //I would then like to print the score to the screen,
    // is there anyway to do this?   


   al_rest(1000);

   return 0;

}
```

Is this possible, or how about converting the score to a `const char` or a `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**al_draw_textf**](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/a5docs/5.0.3/font.html#al_draw_textf) to print a string using a printf-style format string.

Something like this:

```
al_draw_textf(my_font, my_color, x_pos, y_pos, 0, "score = %d", score);
```